# Awful Battery Life After Windows 10 Anniversary Update

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, battery

I am running Windows 10 on a 6 month old Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 460.

I started to notice that I was originally getting about ~6-9 hours of battery life using painting and lite graphics apps, Chrome Browser with a bunch of tabs open.

Then all of a sudden, my battery life went down to about 2 or 3 hours max. I did a battery report, and confirmed that this drop happened over a span of a few days. I cannot trace back this drop to any installed program within this time frame.

I installed battery bar, and saw that my battery had abnormal wear (21%), and then got the battery replaced the other day, however, I am still only getting 5 hours maximum with the most strict battery settings possible.

What I have done to diagnose the problem thus far:
- Turn on windows 10 battery saving mode
- Make sure I am on Battery Saving profile
- Close all background taskbar-apps (bottom right corner)
- Close all background toolbar-apps (main taskbar)

But I am still not getting the desired battery life...

Just to be clear, with no apps running, and screen brightness on about 50%, I used to easily be able to get 9 hours. Now I can get 3 if I am lucky.

I am guessing there is some background service or corrupted driver that is taking up CPU usage in the background. How would I go about diagnosing this other than trying to watch it bounce around in the Task Manager profiler?

It seems that the built-in windows 10 battery usage by app is quite useless in terms of finding this issue.

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE 1:**

I will try a ["clean boot"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135) in Windows to see if that helps, and report back. Might be tedious, but it's better than reformatting...

**UPDATE 2:**

It's very possible that a program called Prey was the culprit. After reading some forums, many users got huge increases from uninstalling this program. 
My CPU usage went from 35+% down to 7-10%. Not sure how much will impact the battery, but it will definitely help.

Also, it is worthwhile to note that with the 'advanced settings' of the windows battery profile configuration (accessible by right clicking the battery icon in the taskbar), there is an option to limit the max CPU usage when on battery. This is hacky though, and would only be done if all else fails... Plus it will slow down your computer.

Comment: Have you considered the battery itself? Is it possible the battery may be failing?

Comment: Thanks, yes the battery was faulty with 21% wear (as stated in the question), and I got it replaced. It did increase the battery life by about 45 minutes. But that's still 3-4 hours compared to 6-9 hours.

Comment: If you have a solution then post it as an answer. Please don't use the forumism of editing the title to say "solved" as that is what we have the green tick on an accepted answer for.

Comment: Why didn't you post an answer to your question !

Comment: the setting app has an entry with battery usage where you can see which apps use most battery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with a program called Prey. The program had some conflicts with the Anniversary update that had destroyed my battery life.

My discharge rate before uninstalling Prey was consistently 13,000-20,000mW
Now I'm sitting at about 3,000-5,000 mW and windows is telling me the battery will last for 12 hours with 89% (unlikely, but still much, much higher than the estimated 2 hours I was getting before)

Answer (score -2):

Well  you can set up Windows' power-saving capacities to release the maximum life out of your laptop's battery.  by unplugging peripherals, for example, external hard drives and memory sticks when they're not being used, you can spare some more power along the way. other things you can do are explained [**here**](http://www.digitalbog.com/2016/01/how-to-improve-battery-life-with.html) in details

Comment: Welcome to Super User. I think you're getting down votes because your answer doesn't appear to add value to this particular question and links to another article without including the relevant details directly in your answer. The latter is frowned upon because should the external site go down your answer becomes less useful